# Remove duplicate tr from cloned variable

Tags: jquery, html-table, duplicates, clone, tablerow

I have a `table` with two rows. I have cloned the entire table using `clone()`. When I export the table to Excel I see duplicate rows in the file because the second row contains a nested table. How can I remove the duplicate rows?

```js
$("#jobExportExcel").click(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var stable = document.createElement("table");
  var sthead = $(table.table().header()).clone(true)[0].outerHTML;
  var sbody = "";
  var row = $('#details').val();

  if (row == 'table') {
    table.$('tr').clone().each(function() { // right here i clone the rows 
      body += this.outerHTML;
    });
  } else {
    table.$('tr').clone().each(function() { // right here i clone the rows 
      body += this.outerHTML;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>sno</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>education</th>
      <th>percentage</th>
      <th>branch name</th>
      <th> ph.no</th>
      <th> address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can remove the nested tables from the cloned content by doing something like this: `var $table = $('table').clone(); $table.find('table').remove();`. From there you can get the content to export to excel.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually i am getting table value from mysql and also need to clone nested table values..so what to do?

Comment: Excel doesn't really handle nested tables, so you need to refactor your html to match the desired (possible) output - ie *start* with the output, not with the html.

Comment: @freedomn-m i want something like to check if there is any duplicates row in the cloned variable that is  **body** variable contains all cloned rows so i need to check if there is any duplicate values in **sbody** if it is..then i need to remove it.

Comment: You need to remove the duplicate content from the DOM element you clone **before** you create the `body` string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you explain me in detail..i am just beginner..